# Finding if max count exceeds allowed set limit

Tags: database, oracle

Have the following trigger to find out the max allowed rentals per month have been exceeded according to limit set in their plan. Code compiles but I'm missing a check. Can anyone help?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER max_dvd_count
BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT
ON RENTAL
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
member_limit NUMBER(2);

BEGIN


SELECT COUNT(RENTAL.MEMBERID) INTO member_limit
FROM MEMBER, MEMBERSHIP, RENTAL
WHERE MEMBERSHIP.MEMBERSHIPID = MEMBER.MEMBERSHIPID
AND MEMBER.MEMBERID = RENTAL.MEMBERID;


raise_application_error (-20000, 'You have exceeded monthly rental limit');
END;
```

Comment: What should be `allowed rentals per month`? You are missing that check only.

Comment: For now you are counting all rows in the three joined tables, which is not what you want apparently.

Comment: for plan1 limit is 4, for plan 2 limit is 99.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that plan1/plan2 are in field `plan_name`. You need to `group by` column `plan_name` and get the count like below. Also, note that I have changed your query, to have explicit join syntax rather than old style implicit join syntax.

```
SELECT COUNT(RENTAL.MEMBERID) INTO member_limit
FROM MEMBER
JOIN MEMBERSHIP ON MEMBERSHIP.MEMBERSHIPID = MEMBER.MEMBERSHIPID
JOIN RENTAL ON MEMBER.MEMBERID = RENTAL.MEMBERID
GROUP BY plan_name;
```

Now you can check the condition easily with a `IF` condition like

```
IF(member_limit > 4) THEN
raise_application_error (-20000, 'You have exceeded monthly rental limit for Plan1');
ELSE
raise_application_error (-20000, 'You have exceeded monthly rental limit for Plan2');
END IF;
```

Comment: this should work, plan1 and plan2 are in a column called membershiptype in the membership table so GROUP BY membershiptype makes sense. Thank you.